# send and receive XML via http post method (REST API) on Android

Tags: android, rest, xmlhttprequest, http-post

My code is crashing all the time and I’m not able to find what is the exact problem. Can anybody tell is this correct method to consume XML data?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8282/attendance/jnd/mark");
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Attendance  type=\"2\" ><sch id=\"7\"/> </Attendance>", HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        request.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        result.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));   
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

logcat:

07-31 13:44:13.533: D/AndroidRuntime(2567): --------- beginning of crash
07-31 13:44:13.533: E/AndroidRuntime(2567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 13:44:13.533: E/AndroidRuntime(2567): Process: comorg.demoapi, PID: 2567
07-31 13:44:13.533: E/AndroidRuntime(2567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{comorg.demoapi/comorg.demoapi.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-31 13:44:13.533: E/AndroidRuntime(2567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
07-31 13:44:13.533: E/AndroidRuntime(2567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

Comment: What your exception is?

Comment: it stopped while running..shows fatal excetion in logcat

Comment: Seeing your exception, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use AndroidHttpRestService.

It's extremmelly easy and makes a lot of work for you.

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It lets you use Get/posts, JSON communications etc.

Edit:

Seeing your exception I can say it's an easy one. You can't make request on the main thread (UI thread). Put your code inside an async task and that's all !!

Comment: Very busy now. I didn't commit an example because instructions are very clear. Please, follow the instruction carefully. You only have to implement one interface and send the request following the doc. Too easy

Comment: can anybody help?? :(